# Symfony OneToOne relation not getting data in user entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I got 2 entities User and Profile. User class code:

```
/**
 * @var Profile
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", inversedBy="user")
 */
private $profile;

/**
 * @param Profile $profile
 * @return $this
 */
public function setProfile($profile)
{
    $this->profile = $profile;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Profile
 */
public function getProfile()
{
    return $this->profile;
}
```

Profile class code:

```
/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="profile")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @param User $user
 * @return $this
 */
public function setUser($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}
```

Now in my database in Profile entity I've got user_id, and in User entity I've got profile_id, but when I'm adding profile in User entity profile_id is NULL. In Profile class user_id is ok, but in User profile_id is set as NULL, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

As previous answerer said - you shouldn't be setting it on both sides. So decide in which side you want.

*One to one relation is basically the same one to many relation, with the only difference that in "mapped" side the entry cannot be more than once.*

You have 2 options there. Setting profile to user or setting user to profile.

1) If at start you create users and then create profiles - you should place setters/getters in profile side

2) If at start you create profiles and then users, you should place setters/getters in user side

You don't need mapped by / inversed by in oneToOne relation...

Check following working code example. (So we will place setters/getters in Profile entity side)

```
/**
 * One Profile has One User.
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;

public function setUser(User $user)
{
   $this->user = $user;
}

public function getUser()
{
   return $this->user();
}
```

ps. In overall, i'm thinking you're trying to make some easy things difficult with this relation. Why not just creating one entity ? Why you need two with one to one relation here ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be setting it on both sides - since the `Profile` has `inversedBy` it is the owning side - hence the result in your database.

Your getters and setters will still work fine - the `JoinColumn` on `user_id` annotation is taking care of the relationship and `profile_id` is not actually being specified anywhere and is superfluous in your DB.